# GAS: BigQuery Upload to Existing table

Tags: json, rest, google-apps-script, google-bigquery, ringcentral

I have over 350,000 RingCentral Call logs I want to upload to BigQuery so I can use SQL queries to pull and digest in reports. They are currently stored as 23 .csv files to keep each under the 10MB limit imposed by the BigQuery API. I want to use Google Apps Script to upload the CSV data so all 350K entries are in one table. Here is the code I have so far:

```js
function uploadCSVtoBigQuery() {
  
  try {
    
  var CSVFolder = "Drive ID to Folder A";
  var ProcessedFolder = "Drive ID to Folder B";
  
  var projectId = 'ring-central-call-logs';
  var datasetId = 'RingCentral';
  var tableId   = 'Calls';
  
  //CSVFolder = getDriveFolder(CSVFolder);
  var CSVFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(CSVFolder);
  //ProcessedFolder = getDriveFolder(ProcessedFolder);
  var ProcessedFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(ProcessedFolder); 
  
  if (CSVFolder && ProcessedFolder) {
    Logger.log("Folders Appear Valid");
    var data, job, file, files = CSVFolder.getFiles();
    
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      
      file = files.next();
      
      if (file.getMimeType() === "text/csv") {
        
        data = file.getBlob().setContentType('application/octet-stream');
        
        job = {
          configuration: {
            load: {
              destinationTable: {
                projectId: projectId,
                datasetId: datasetId,
                tableId: tableId
              },
              skipLeadingRows: 1
            }
          }
        };

        job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId, data);
        file.makeCopy(file.getName(), ProcessedFolder);
        file.setTrashed(true);

        Logger.log('Job status for %s https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/jobs/%s', file.getName(), projectId);
      } else{Logger.log(file.getMimeType()+" Is not a valid file type.");}
    }
    
  } else{Logger.log('One of your folders is not valid');}
    
   Logger.log('Finished'); 
  } catch(e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }
}

// Return the ID of the Google Drive nested folder
function getDriveFolder(name) {
  
  var results, folders = name.split("\\");
  var folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  
  for (var i=0; i<folders.length; i++) {
    if (folders[i] === "") continue;
    results = folder.getFoldersByName(folders[i]);
    if (results.hasNext()) {
      folder = results.next(); 
    } else {
      folder = folder.createFolder(folders[i]);
    }
  }
  
  return folder;
}
```

On running the function I get a JSON response as follows:

```
 GoogleJsonResponseException: Using table ring-central-call-logs:RingCentral.Calls is not allowed for this operation because of its type. Try using a different table that is of type TABLE.
```

To check my brain, I tried running the REST API in the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/bigquery/v2/bigquery.tabledata.insertAll?projectId=ring-central-call-logs&datasetId=RingCentral&tableId=Calls&_h=1&resource=%257B%250A%20%20%2522skipInvalidRows%2522%253A%20true%252C%250A%20%20%2522rows%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%255B%250A%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522json%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522User%2522%253A%20%2522Nathaniel%20MacIver%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522CallStartTime%2522%253A%20%25222018-07-09%2015%253A45%253A10%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522From%2522%253A%20%2522123456789%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522To%2522%253A%20%25229876543211%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522DurationSeconds%2522%253A%20%252215%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522CallDirection%2522%253A%20%2522out%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522CallResult%2522%253A%20%2522Failed%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522QueueName%2522%253A%20%2522Test%20Queue%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%255D%252C%250A%20%20%2522kind%2522%253A%20%2522bigquery%2523tableDataInsertAllRequest%2522%250A%257D&), like this:

```js
POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/ring-central-call-logs/datasets/RingCentral/tables/Calls/insertAll?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
 
{


 "skipInvalidRows": true,
 "rows": [
  {
   "json": {
    "User": "Nathaniel",
    "CallStartTime": "2018-07-09 15:45:10",
    "From": "123456789",
    "To": "9876543211",
    "DurationSeconds": "15",
    "CallDirection": "out",
    "CallResult": "Failed",
    "QueueName": "Test Queue"
   }
  }
 ],
 "kind": "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest"
}
```

And got this similar error:

```js
400
 
- Show headers -
  
{
 "error": {
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Cannot add rows to a table of type EXTERNAL.",
  "errors": [
   {
    "message": "Cannot add rows to a table of type EXTERNAL.",
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid"
   }
  ],
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
 }
}
```

Screenshot here for Schema looks to match what I am inputting:
[image]
 I would suppose I have permissions issue by reading it, but I can run a Query function in GAS just fine. Could I get assistance to figure out why this isn't working? Thank you!

Comment: is destination table actually an external table? that's what the error says! if so - have you just tried using native BigQuery table?

Comment: Sounds like you need to import the data to a new table that is within BigQuery, and not a linked table. If the call data is already available in Ring Central, couldn't you just stream it to BQ for analysis?

Comment: Yep, Totally forgot I added data as a CSV to start off, just didn't realize that made it an external table. Good Idea tehowch, I'll have to see if Ring Central supports that easily.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Where is the data/files that you want to load - in Drive or GCS?

Comment: It's in my Google Drive. Even now, Google sheets keeps messing with the formatting of my data column in the .csv's I upload, so I'm still trying to find an easier way to add these 350K entries to the Bigquery table. Are there any resources around to teach how to access Ring Cental API from Google Apps Script?